# Java : String Concatenation

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation

I found this code

```
public class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello";  
        s.concat("world");
        System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

and thought that output should be

> Helloworld

but it print only

> Hello

what is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A String is an immutable object. This means that your String s will never change no matter how many times you print it. So what does the concat method do then? When you look at the api (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) you can see that The result of concat on string is a new string so this would return what you expect:

```
public class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello";  
        String newS = s.concat("world");
        System.out.println(newS);

    }
}
```